# "not found suite class" error when trying to execute play project in Intellij IDEA 14.0.3

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, intellij-14

I am trying to work with Play Framework (2.3) using "play-java" template.
Also, I would like to use Intellij IDEA IDE (14.0.3).

To do so, I execute the following commands:

```
1) activator new app-name play-java

2) cd app-name

3) activator app-name idea
```

Next, I open the created project with Intellij IDEA without modifying any parameters of the project.

When I try to run the project I always get the following error:

"error running specs2 in 'app': not found suite class."

How could I fix that error ?

Comment: Did you solve it? Having same issue here...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after importing some code into an intellij project, it wouldn't run any.
I then created a brand new one via intellij, and this one ran correctly.

As it turns out the only difference was that the one created via intellij had a package definition and not mines. (i.e.: package )

So when intellij was trying to find all the tests in the package it found none as my tests were in no package.
Just adding the package definition in all my tests solved the problem, it can now run them.